# SSL on Apache Tomcat 6 as windows service not running

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, ssl

I have installed Apache Tomcat 6 as windows service.I have created self-signed Certificate for SSL implementation.And also made changes in server.xml for SSL.

Now when I start Tomcat 6 as command line then I could connect through https:// .
But when I start Tomcat 6 as service then https:// didn't work.

If anybody have idea then please tell the solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Define "didn't work".

Comment: I solved it.There was Problem in the location of .keystore file.